# How to pass parameters to view-id in Pretty-Faces?

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I want to pass some variable values to the view-id node in the pretty-config.xml configuration file. For sample:

I want to do something like that:

```
 <url-mapping id="allReports">
        <pattern value="/report/#{type}" />
        <view-id value="/pages/report/#{type}.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>
```

But I got the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in fragment at index 18: http://localhost/#{type}.xhtml
```

Someone know how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Prettyfaces main website](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) says, you have to do the following one:

```
<url-mapping id="view-user">
    <pattern value="/user/{username}" />
    <view-id value="/user/view.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

This is the equivalent to `/user/view.xhtml?username=yourParam`. If you type this url `/user/Administrator`, you receive in your view a request parameter which name is `username` and value is `Administrator`. Just follow this convention.

If you want to **inherit** from a parent id, just [write a mapping for each type](http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.mapping.parents). For instance you can write:

```
<url-mapping parentId="view-user" id="admins">
   <pattern value="/admin/#{user}" /> 
   <view-id value="/user/admins/view.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping parentId="view-user" id="externals">
    <pattern value="/external/#{user}" /> 
    <view-id value="/user/externals/view.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Also you have [dynamic view id's](http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.dynaview), but I think it's not possible to concat them with a static String piece. To use them in the way you want you should take the param from the request and process the complete destination url in your bean.

Comment: But I dont want query-param style. Path-param istead. It´s possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I created it like that:

pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping id="static">
    <pattern value="/s/#{staticViewBean.requestPath}" />
    <view-id value="#{staticViewBean.getViewId}" />
</url-mapping>
```

StaticViewBean.java

```
@Controller("staticViewBean")
@Scope("request")
public class StaticViewBean {

    private String requestPath;

    public String getViewId() {
        return "/WEB-INF/pages/s/" + requestPath + ".xhtml";
    }

    public String getRequestPath() {
        return requestPath;
    }

    public void setRequestPath(String requestPath) {
        this.requestPath = requestPath;
    }

}
```